# XCode 5 No ad-hoc distribution option for project

Tags: iphone, xcode5, ipa

For most of the ios projects I have made I go to Organizer/Archive, select an archive, click on distribution and get three options: Submit to ios App Store,Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Distribution, and Export as Xcode archive. I select the second option and I asm alble to create an ipa file that will in stall on an iphone. However, for one of my projects when I click on distribute I only get the options: Save Built Products and Export as Xcode Archive. Neither of these options creates an ipa file and I can't distribute the app. I have looked at all of the configuration options in the app and nothing stands out as different from the configuration oif the apps that work.

How can I get the ad-hoc option to shoiw up?

Comment: Are your provisionings configured properly?

Comment: I am using the same provisioning file for several projects and all of the other projects give me the ad-hoc option.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're including multiple build targets as part of the archive. An iOS app can only have 1 product as part of the bundle, otherwise it'll refuse to create the application.

You need to:
1. Go to the project settings
2. Select the application target
3. Select 'Build Settings'
4. Search for the term 'Install'
5. Change 'Skip Install' from NO to YES

More context on the 'Skip Install' option can be found here: [Xcode 4 target build setting "Skip install". What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374851/xcode-4-target-build-setting-skip-install-what-is-it)

Comment: I changed skip install to Yes and still don't get the option. All my other projects that work have skip install set to no.

Comment: Are you including any other products as part of your application? As stated above, you'll receive the options you're getting when archiving if your applications includes more than one product.

Comment: Yes. I have a library that is being built for use in the program

Comment: When I selected the second target and said Skip Install - Yes it worked and let me generate an .ipa file! Thanks for the help.