# xcframework does not contain internal frameworks

Tags: frameworks, xcodebuild

I am trying to create an `.xcframework` file for a few third party libraries I'm using. Following the instructions from https://appspector.com/blog/xcframeworks, I

1. Create platform-specific `framework` files:

```
# Archive for device
xcodebuild archive -scheme TestFramework -destination="iOS" -archivePath /tmp/xcf/ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

# Archive for simulator
xcodebuild archive -scheme TestFramework -destination="iOS Simulator" -archivePath /tmp/xcf/iossimulator.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```

At this point, I've gotten two frameworks with `.swiftmodule` files; everything looks good. The frameworks do *not* come with `.swiftinterface` files, but I think that is alright as these are objc projects. Then, I

2. Combine the individual `framework`s to form a single `xcframework` file:

```
# Build xcframework with two archives
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework /tmp/xcf/ios.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/TestFramework.framework -framework /tmp/xcf/iossimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/TestFramework.framework -output /tmp/xcf/TestFramework.xcframework
```

Here, `xcodebuild` doesn't *fail*, but it emits a curious error:

```
No 'swiftinterface' files found within '/Users/user/git/ReactiveObjC/output/xcf/ios.xcarchive/Products/Products/Library/TestFramework.framework/Modules/TestFramework.swiftmodule'.
```

Crucially, the `.xcframework` package does not contain the individual `framework`s **or** folders specified in the `Info.plist` file. Obviously, when I try to link to the `xcframework` in this state, I get a bunch of "missing symbols" linker errors.

Why is this? What must I do to get `xcodebuild` to create the `xcframework` completely?

NB: Manually creating the folders seems to work for now, but this feels wrong and is brittle – Apple can change the way `xcodebuild` works anytime.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out that adding `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES` to the end of the `xcodebuild` command was not enough / not working to produce a framework with the required `swiftinterface` files. I had to go in the settings for the actual project and manually set `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` to `YES`, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656323/1566730) suggests. After I got the frameworks with the `swiftinterface` files, I was then able to create the `xcframework` file using `xcodebuild` without any problems.

Comment: You used the wrong key, try adding `BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES` (note the plural) to `xcodebuild`

Comment: FWIW: Checking the documentation bar in Xcode, they list `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` as the correct key.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to build XCFramework from xcarchives, however I can't find BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION in project setting, need help :(( thx

Comment: Hi, how can I specify BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION on a swift package? it seems that from xcodebuild the flag is not passed

Answer (score 4):

**Create XCFramework**

XCFramework replaces Fat/Universal framework. It is a `bundle` which contains multiple .framewok for each architecture/platform. We don't need to use `lipo`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215277/4770877) for unite and separate frameworks manually

XCFramework supports libraries with headers and Objective-C

1. Enable `Build Libraries for Distribution(BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION)` for your framework. XCFramework works only with enabled [[BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305234/4770877). If not when you run **step 3** `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` you get (or don't)

   ```
   No 'swiftinterface' files found within '<some_path>/<some_name>.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/<some_name>.framework/Modules/<some_name>.swiftmodule'
   ```
2. Build/archive .framework for different architectures/platforms

   ```
    xcodebuild archive \
       -workspace ModuleName.xcworkspace \
       -scheme "schemaName" \
       -sdk "iphoneos" \
       -arch arm64 \
       -archivePath "<some_path>/ArchiveName1.xcarchive" \
       SKIP_INSTALL=NO \

    xcodebuild archive \
       -workspace ModuleName.xcworkspace \
       -scheme "schemaName" \
       -sdk "iphonesimulator" \
       -arch x86_64 \
       -archivePath "<some_path>/ArchiveName2.xcarchive" \
       SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
   ```

   `SKIP_INSTALL`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67180392/4770877) one of key point to include framework inside archive
3. Create XCFramework using `xcodebuild -create-xcframework`

   ```
   xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
       -framework "<some_path>/ArchiveName1.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ModuleName.framework" \
       -debug-symbols "<some_path>/ArchiveName1.xcarchive/dSYMs/${schemes[$n]}.ModuleName.dSYM" \
       -framework "<some_path>/ArchiveName2.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ModuleName.framework"
   ```

`-debug-symbols` allows to add `.dSYM`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219237/4770877) and `.BCSymbolMap`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274795/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

**Converting to XCFramework from Cocoapods**

For my scenario, I'm trying to build XCFrameworks from the FAT/lipo frameworks generated by cocoapods.

I added this to the end of my podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

This ensured the frameworks were compiled correctly and I was able to run the normal `xcodebuild -create-xcframework ...` command to generate the XCFramework.

Note: I'm also using the `cocoapods-binary` plugin to pre-build all the pods frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. It turned out that Xcode 13's build settings override the SKIP_INSTALL=NO flag in the command line. Once I set this field in project's build setting to NO (and made sure on the way that the Build Library For Distribution is set to YES) I managed to create the xcframework file successfully.

Comment: Follow instruction from this for creating xc framework

Answer (score 0):

I have added readme file with full details how to create xc framework.

https://github.com/awasthi027/Xcode_lib_framework_issues/blob/master/README.md

Follow instruction from this for creating xc framework